# How to enable or browse web service running on EC2 on local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, emr, x11-forwarding

I have EC2 instance that has port forwarding enabled for EMR cluster.  Ganglia monitoring service is already running on EMR.  I am able to browse Ganglia from EC2 instance with following using "text browser" Lynx.

```
lynx http://localhost:5000/ganglia
```

However,  I want to access this service from my local machine ( Mac Yosemite ).  I did some research and found that I need X11 port forwarding.  So now I also have X11 port forwarding enabled.

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

gives me following on EC2 instance

```
localhost:14.0
```

I am also able to run  "xclock" and it launches clock on my local machine.

I tried to ssh into EC2 instance with this syntax .

```
 ssh -C -c blowfish -N -L:1050:myEc2Server:5000 myUser@myEc2Server
```

Then if I type http://127.0.0.1:1050/ganglia in google chrome I get message saying no data received.

Can anyone point out what is going wrong ?  I tried verbose log from local machine to Ec2 instance and it has following message -

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

In short, I want to be able to see Ganglia from local machine.  Any help is appreciated.

~Cheers

Comment: Whosoever down voted can you explain why ?

Answer (score 1):

I tested an ssh command line from my own laptop (Mac Yosemite) and the following works

```
ssh -N -L:1050:localhost:5000 username@public-dns-of-ec2-instance
```

After this is connected, I verified using:
http://localhost:1050/ganglia.

In your command line above, you may just need to replace myEc2Server with localhost or 127.0.0.1.